# How to report a bug from a specific plasma widget?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, plasma

I just installed Kubuntu 18.04 and everything is going better than expected. However I have stumbled upon a problem with the Timer Widget (I'm guessing: my system is in Spanish and it is called "Cronómetro") that I put in my desktop: If I set one minute, the clock reversed back to 0 two seconds at a time every second, then finalizing in 30 seconds.

In https://bugs.kde.org I fail to find where should I report this annoying bug: either as widget or as plasmoid, there is no evident group where it belongs.

In the meantime, I guess I should use ktimer, where the problem is not there.

Comment: You can ask for guidance at https://www.kubuntuforums.net

Comment: If https://askubuntu.com/a/1029569/248158 provides you with the answer, please accept it.

Comment: Not an answer, but the bug has been reported on kde.org and launchpad: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=381173 and https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/kdeplasma-addons/+bug/1771094

Answer (score 2):

**Ubuntu packages**

Ubuntu Packages Search: https://packages.ubuntu.com

Searching: plasma widget + bionic

[image]

Two hits: https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=plasma+widget&searchon=names&suite=bionic&section=all

Package plasma-widgets-addons has the timer: https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/plasma-widgets-addons -> https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/plasma-widgets-addons/filelist

Source name:  kdeplasma-addons

[image]

**KDE Bug tracker**

KDE Bugtracking System : https://bugs.kde.org/

Search first existing bugs (1)

**Product**: kdeplasma-addons (from the Ubuntu source)

[image]

**Component**: timer

[image]

**(1) Timer bugs**

Component: timer Product: kdeplasma-addons

[https://bugs.kde.org/buglist.cgi?bug_status=**open**&component=timer&product=kdeplasma-addons](https://bugs.kde.org/buglist.cgi?bug_status=__open__&component=timer&product=kdeplasma-addons)